# How to stop the spin.js spinner with jQuery

Tags: jquery, spinner

just used the cool spin.js (http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) with jQuery.

I'm appending the spinner with something like this

```
$('#students-list td:nth-child(5)').live('ajax:before', function(){
  $(this).append().spin(spinOpts);
});
```

But can't stop it after an Ajax complete event.
How to call stop() method on it ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: please mark accepted answer below

Answer (score 35):

Are you using the jQuery plugin listed at the end of that page?  If so do this:

```
$('#students-list td:nth-child(5)').spin(false);
```

or

```
$('#students-list td:nth-child(5)').data('spinner').stop();
```

To stop it.